# AccountHierarchy is already in production but showing "variable is not defined" in sandbox?

Tags: apex

I have a really strange error.

```
Variable does not exist: AccountHierarchy in Zeile 70, Spalte 24
```

Code:

```
childIDs = AccountHierarchy.AccountStructure(parentID);
contactIDs = AccountHierarchy.AllContacts(childIDs);
```

The code is like this already in production and was last updated on 28th or april 2015. So it seemed to work just one month ago. What could have changed, so that this code is suddenly not working anymore?

When I open the class in our sandbox and just try to save it instantly, it causes this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm that the apex class `AccountHierarchy` exists in your sandbox? It sounds like the class isn't there.

Comment: Lol woops, I'm stupid! I didn't see any AccountHierarchy declaration, but I forgot that you can use global classes without constructing them.... You are right, if you want, you can put this in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't recognize `AccountHierarchy` as a name, which implies that there is no apex class by that name in the sandbox. If this class doesn't exist in the sandbox, you should deploy it from production down to the sandbox in order for this code to work properly.